# Align bottom nested item in display:table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Let's assume that I got a row with 3 items inside (CSS inside style tag for simplify).

```
<div style="display:table">
    <div style="display:table-cell">
        <span>Some text</span>
        <button type="button">Some button</button>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell">
        <span>Some Other text</span>
        <button type="button">Some button</button>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell">
        <span>Long Long Long Long Long Long Long text </span>
        <button type="button">Some button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I change that issue that all the three buttons will be in the same line, no matter what the length of the text ? 
Now the texts are not equal and then the buttons not at the same line.

Comment: Have you considered splitting the '<span>texts</span>' part and the '<button>...' parts in different rows?

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the styling (That is non existent).

You need to add a row to separate the content.

https://jsfiddle.net/yoxer670/

```
    <div style="display:table">
  <div style="display: table-row">
    <div style="display:table-cell" class="tableCell">
        <span>Some text</span>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell" class="tableCell">
        <span>Some Other text</span>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell" class="tableCell">
        <span>Long Long Long Long Long Long Long text </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-row">
    <div style="display:table-cell" class="tableCell">
        <button type="button">Some button</button>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell" class="tableCell">
        <button type="button">Some button</button>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell" class="tableCell">
        <button type="button">Some button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to avoid this solution but its works.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change the html code, you can use only css style.
I added .cell class to the table-cells.

```
.cell {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.cell button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```